# ActiveRecord AVG calculation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord, average

I have request:

```
Model.group(:p_id).pluck("AVG(desired)")
=> [0.77666666666666667e1, 0.431666666666666667e2, ...]
```

but when I ran SQL

```
SELECT AVG(desired) AS desired
FROM model
GROUP BY p_id
```

I got

```
 -----------------
|      desired    |
|-----------------|
| 7.76666666666667|
|43.1666666666667 |
|       ...       |
 -----------------
```

What is the reason of this? Sure I can multiply, but I bet where are should be an explanation.

I found that

```
Model.group(:p_id).pluck("AVG(desired)").map{|a| a.to_f} 
=> [7.76666666666667,43.1666666666667, ...]
```

Now I'm struggle with other task, I need numbers attributes in pluck so my request is:

```
Model.group(:p_id).pluck("p_id, AVG(desired)")
```

how to get correct AVG value in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0.77666666666666667e1` *is* (almost) `7.76666666666667`, they're the same number in two different representations with slightly different precision. If you dump the first one into `irb`, you'll see:

```
> 0.77666666666666667e1
 => 7.766666666666667
```

When you perform an `avg` in the database, the result has type `numeric` which ActiveRecord represents using Ruby's `BigDecimal`. The `BigDecimal` values are being displayed in scientific notation but that shouldn't make any difference when you format your data for display.

In any case, `pluck` isn't the right tool for this job, you want to use `average`:

```
Model.group(:p_id).average(:desired)
```

That will give you a Hash which maps `p_id` to averages. You'll still get the averages in `BigDecimal`s but that really shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @mu-is-to-short
Thank you for your answer, that's good explanation, but where is two things:
1. your code return hash with BigDecimal
2. I still have to use pluck cause I have 6 different calculations on different fields.

Comment: But what's the problem with `BigDecimal`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found solution:

```
Model.group(:p_id).pluck("p_id, AVG(Round(desired))")
=> [[1,7.76666666666667],[2,43.1666666666667], ...]
```